# How to provide parameters to different types of components?

Tags: design-patterns, composition, godot

I am developing an rpg simulation game in Godot, where NPCs are driven by their needs as in 'The Sims'.

I have an `Entity` class that represents the NPC:

```py
class_name Entity extends Node2D

var components:[Component]
var ai:AI

func _init():
    components.append(MovementComponent.new(self))
    components.append(AttackComponent.new(self))
    components.append(InteractComponent.new(self))

func _update(delta):
    var action = ai.evaluate_needs() # action now needs to be provided to the correct component
    for c in components:
        c.set_action(action)
        c.update(delta)
```

The Entity class uses composition to add or remove functionalities (components) to the NPC.
There is an AI class that evaluates the needs of the NPC and returns an appropriate `Action` to execute by the components.

*MoveAction.gd*

```py
class_name MoveAction extends Action

var target_position:Vector2
var interruptable:bool
```

An Action is just a data class holding information on what the component has to do. In the case of the `MoveAction` the `MoveComponent` should move the NPC to the `target_position`. An `AttackAction` would contain information for the `AttackComponent` which combat skill to use on who.

A component looks like this:

```py
class_name MoveComponent extends Component

var current_target: Vector2
var myself:Entity
var action:Action

func _init(entity:Entity):
    myself = entity

func set_action(action:Action):
    self.action = action

func _update(delta):
    # calculate and update position with the data inside the action
```

Now I think about how to provide the components with the correct actions. When there is a `MoveAction` only the `MoveComponent` should handle this.
I consider to create marker interfaces for each existing component. Then every action would implement the corresponding interface, e.g. `class_name MoveAction extends MoveComponentInterface`.
This action then  would be provided to every component. The component would then just check inside the `setter` `if action is MoveComponentInterface`.

Am I using actions correctly? These are actually the decisions in the utility ai method.

What would be a better approach? Is there a design pattern for this kind of problem?

Comment: If there is a designated component per action, why don't you put components in a dictionary and pick the correct one for the action at hand?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `components ={MoveComponentInterface: MoveComponent, ...}` and then pick the component by calling: `components[action].set_action(action)`?
This is definitely better then setting the action for all components.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to decrease the abstraction, and keep it simple.

Do you actually want multiple components to be executing at the same time? This makes things a lot more complex, because they can be conflicting. Yet this is what your `[Component]` and `for c in components` allow.

I would allow a component to execute the action itself, no need for separate 'Action' classes. More like strategies, as in the strategy pattern. Lets call them behaviors.
Behavior has a simple `execute(entity)` function.

The role of the AI is then to simply select ONE active behavior. The entity itself does not need to contain the list of possible behaviors, the AI does.

In the entity `update`, you would call the AI and allow it to think about which behavior it wants, and return it.
Then the entity simply executes this behavior, providing it with a reference to itself.
The behavior would have access to the entity properties and methods to allow the actual moving, attacking, etc...

A basic state machine, the AI decides which state (behavior) we are in. You might not need state transitions, just code that executes when you are inside a state.

To get a more complex simulation, you could create a hierarchy of AIs. A high-level AI selects which task AI to activate, and the task AI provides the behavior steps.

Eg: the high-level AI decides to activate the build-a-house-task and this build-a-house-task activates, in sequence, a movement behavior towards a pile of stones, then a movement behavior towards the building location, etc...